# Mail blocked from Windows Server 2016, but not since 2008

Tags: windows, email, powershell, smtp, shared-hosting

Good Morning:

I'm running exactly the same script from two different virtual machines:

- The first in Windows Server 2008 R2
- The second in Windows Server 2016

Features

- The SMTP is an external service of a hosting (BlueHost)
- The script does not generate an error
- The mail arrives in both cases to internal addresses (from BlueHost)
- **The mail does not reach external addresses (like gmail) in the second case (Win 2016)**
- Both VMs run on the same desktop
- Both VMs have antivirus and Firewall disabled

I'm looking for help to understand where the problem is. I think there is some strange configuration in Windows 2016 that causes BlueHost to block it or Gmail does not receive it.

I have tried many things, but I arrived at a very strange point, in which I do not understand what happens.

This is the script I use to test, only for test purposes. Since the same error is generated by sending the email from SQL Server Databasemail.

```
$EmailTo = "blabla@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "blabla@mydomain.com.ar"
$Subject = "Test a" 
$Body = "Test Body" 
$SMTPServer = "mail.mydomain.com.ar" 
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 26) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("blabla@mydomain.com.ar", "pass"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

**Tested with Send-MailMessage and same error:**

```
$from = "bla@bla.com.ar" 
$to = "bla@gmail.com" 
$smtp = "mail.bla.com.ar" 
$sub = "hi" 
$body = "test mail 2"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($from, $secpasswd)
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Subject $sub -Body $body -Credential $mycreds -SmtpServer $smtp -DeliveryNotificationOption Never -BodyAsHtml -Port 26
```

Some help? Thanks since now!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: How do the two VMs connect to the Internet? If they appear to have different public IP addresses, then SPF is very likely the culprit.

Comment: No error. Mail not delivered in Win 2016 to external accounts only. Same public IP, same internet conection. What can I investigate on SPF?

Comment: Is your SMTP server actually listening on port 26 or is that a typo?

Also, have you read the documentation on the SmtpClient (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)  Looks like the API is now obsolete.  They are recommending a couple other options, one being https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Comment: Your script does not even appear to be checking for the error.

Comment: Thanks Tim & Michael. Yes, port 26 is OK. ¿Have you got any power shell script recomendation to make a simple email test? Witch error check and no obsolete API?

Comment: Added script not obsolete with Send-MailMessage

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the problem by changing the name of the **computer**. After looking for differences between the VMs, I noticed checking the headers of the emails, that the name of the computer appeared in the header. I changed it and it started to work. As if in some way, that name would be blocked ...